# Issues linking GLUT and QGLViewer

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4, glut

I am trying to compile a computer vision library by Hernan Badino, named [QCV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qcv/) but I am having a lot of linking issues related to the QGLViewer library.
The errors that the compiler throws are:

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQGLViewer.so.2: undefined reference to `gluNewQuadric'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQGLViewer.so.2: undefined reference to `gluUnProject'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQGLViewer.so.2: undefined reference to `gluCylinder'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQGLViewer.so.2: undefined reference to `gluPickMatrix'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQGLViewer.so.2: undefined reference to `gluSphere'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQGLViewer.so.2: undefined reference to `gluProject'
```

which are linking issues related (i suppose) to the OpenGL/GLUT library. I am compiling using CMake, and in the CMakeLists.txt files the GLUT dependency is correctly requested (and found). The relevant part of the CMake file is here:

```
##################################
# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(imgPlayer ${QT_LIBRARIES} 
                                ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY}
                                ${QCV_LIB} 
                                ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} 
                                ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and the outputs of "cmake ." are

```
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 (found version "4.8.6") 
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
-- Found GLUT: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so  
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.2.0") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

what are the possible reasons why the compiler is failing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

GLU is not GLUT. The references missing are from the GLU library. In CMake

```
target_link_libraries(
    …
    ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY}
    …
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately adding ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY} in the CMakeLists does not resolve the issue. The makefile correctly adds the flag -lGLU along all the others (-rdynamic -lQtOpenGL -lQtGui -lQtXml -lQtCore **-lGLU** -lGL -lglut -lXmu -lXi -lqcv) but the linking error persists..